# During the Dominion War, were there any problems with deserters?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

The Dominion war was brutal. Single battles like Wolf 359 or Sector 001 were devastating enough--in both cases, 10,000 or more lives were lost. But the Dominion War had several of those battles, some of which saw the loss of many dozens of Starfleet ships. There could potentially be many people who would be terrified of dying quickly on the front lines, out in the cold of space, dozens or hundreds of light years away from their home planet. Were officers allowed to leave their ships? If so, were there any mentions of this? Or was there some kind of system forcing officers to remain in service? Or did most officers serve with honor, bravely deciding to stay with their ships and fellow crewmembers?

Comment: Jake encounters an ensign who shot himself in the foot in ***[DS9: Nor the Battle to the Strong](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/502.txt)***